# create a list of all the subsets of a given list in python 3.x

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

how can I create a list of all the subsets of a given list in python 3.x?
the list given be like `[1,2,3]` and i want an output like

```
[[1],[2],[3],[1,2],[2,3],[1,3],[1,2,3],[]]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to get the combinations:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> xs = [1, 2, 3]

>>> itertools.combinations(xs, 2)  # returns an iterator
<itertools.combinations object at 0x7f88f838ff48>
>>> list(itertools.combinations(xs, 2))  # yields 2-length subsequences
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]


>>> for i in range(0, len(xs) + 1):  # to get all lengths: 0 to 3
...     for subset in itertools.combinations(xs, i):
...         print(list(subset))
... 
[]
[1]
[2]
[3]
[1, 2]
[1, 3]
[2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
```

combining with list comprehension, you will get what you want:

```
>>> [list(subset) for i in range(0, len(xs) + 1)
                  for subset in itertools.combinations(xs, i)]
[[], [1], [2], [3], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: Without using the combinations, is there any other alternative

Comment: @RISHABHBANSAL, As far as I know, using `itertools.combinations` is simplest. Without it, you need to make a recursive function.

Answer (score 8):

The question is really to ask the powerset. Here is another way to generate it:
(without the itertools.combinations())

```
>>> L = [1, 2, 3]
>>> res = [[]]
>>> for e in L:
    res += [sub + [e] for sub in res]

>>> res
[[], [1], [2], [1, 2], [3], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Or you can just use this 3rd party lib **more_itertools**: **powerset** (as the name aptly reflects its purpose).

```
>>> import more_itertools

>>> list(more_itertools.powerset(L))
[(), (1,), (2,), (3,), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

**You don't need to install `more_intertools` if you're going to use only one function from there.** You can check [Itertools Recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) from the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) documentation. It has such recipe:

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))
```

Actually, `more_itertools.powerset` has exactly the same [implemention](https://github.com/more-itertools/more-itertools/blob/master/more_itertools/recipes.py#L437).

Answer (score 0):

I tried this. without recursion. which worked out successfully.

A is list , K is length of every subset

```
    def subsets(A,K):
       sets = []
       for j in range(len(A)-K+1):
           mySet = []
           for i in range(j,K+j):  
               mySet.append(A[i])
           sets.append(mySet)
    return sets
```

Comment: This is equivalent to `def subsets(A, K): return [A[j:K+j] for j in range(len(A)-K+1)]` but it doesn't return all the subsets of length `K`, only the contiguous ones. For instance, `subsets([1,2,3], 2)` returns `[[1,2], [2,3]]` and misses `[1,3]`.